# row level before insert trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

I am creating row level trigger for `product` table that would be triggered before Insert operation is performed on a product. This trigger will insert a new record in product table if it's type is available in `product_type_master` table.

```
SQL> select * from Product_master;

        ID NAME            PRICE TYPE
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
        1 keyboard         3077 ip
        2 monitor          9847 op
        3 usb               807 sto

 SQL> select * from type_master;

        NO TYPE
---------- --------------------
        1 in
        2 op
        3 sto
```

So the condition is if the new inserting type is equal to the type given in type_master table then only it should be inserted, oherwise not.

I have created one:

```
create or replace trigger ins_trigger
   2  before insert on product_master for each row
   3  begin
   4      if(:new.type == type.type_master)then
   5          insert into product_master values('id',name,'price',type);
   6      end if;
   7  end;
   8  /

   Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: A [foreign key](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/) would do a better job here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the column `type` from the table `type_master` via `type.type_master`. You have to select it.

If you create a foreign key constraint to the master table you don't need a trigger at all:

> ALTER TABLE product_master ADD CONSTRAINT
> product_master_type_master_fk FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES
> type_master(type);

And you don't have to do the insert statement in the trigger. The trigger is triggered from an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the tables like this:

```
create table product_types
( type_id       integer generated always as identity constraint product_type_pk primary key
, type_name     varchar2(30) not null constraint type_name_uk unique );

create table products
( prod_id       integer generated always as identity constraint product_pk primary key
, prod_name     varchar2(30) not null constraint product_name_uk unique
, prod_price    number(10,2)
, prod_type_id  constraint product_type_fk references product_types(type_id) );
```

so that you can't enter an invalid product type:

```
insert into products (prod_name, prod_price, prod_type_id)
values ('Cheese', 123.45, 1);

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (WILLIAM.PRODUCT_TYPE_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

However, just to demonstrate trigger syntax (as there is no need for this trigger), if I had to write one it would be:

```
create or replace trigger really_should_be_a_foreign_key
    before insert or update on products
    for each row when (new.prod_type_id is not null)
declare
    l_parent_type_count number;
begin
    select count(*) into l_parent_type_count
    from   product_types t
    where  t.type_id = :new.prod_type_id;
    
    if l_parent_type_count = 0 then
        raise_application_error
        ( -20000
        , 'Product type "'||:new.prod_type_id||'" is not defined.' ); 
    end if;
end really_should_be_a_foreign_key;
```

Then attempting to enter an invalid product type fails with the error message from the trigger:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Product type "1" is not defined.
ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.REALLY_SHOULD_BE_A_FOREIGN_KEY", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WILLIAM.REALLY_SHOULD_BE_A_FOREIGN_KEY'
```

Comment: Hey , can you please explain me bit about the trigger.

Comment: I made it `before insert or update`, not just `before insert`, because you want to prevent updates with invalid values too. `when (new.prod_type_id is not null)` so it only performs the check when there is an actual type id (assuming that is an optional column). `if` syntax doesn't have brackets, and the equality operator is `=`, not `==` (same as SQL). See [documentation for raise_application_error()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1).

Answer (score 0):

Other's have addressed your approach, but I don't see anyone addressing

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

When you get this, you should immediately follow up with 'show errors'

ANd when you do you should find that the '==' is invalid.  Check your [PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-76918747-C18D-452E-89FB-2C09661C53D3), 2.7.5.2.1 Arithmetic Comparisons